# Preguntar si quiere ingresar otro dato en c# (do... while)

Tags: c#

Preguntar al usuario desde consola, que al terminar de ingresar datos, pregunte si quiere ingresar otro dato, al contestar que `"si"` repite el ciclo.

Comment: ¿Podrías ser más específico? Porque puedes usar desde recursion hasta llamar un método desde un botón u otra acción.

Comment: Mira este es un ejemplo en C: http://www.carlospes.com/curso_de_lenguaje_c/03_02_repetitiva_hacer_mientras.php (EJERCICIO 2)

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque según el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): preguntas solicitando ayuda con trabajo escolar deben incluir un resumen del trabajo que has realizado hasta el momento para resolver el problema y una descripción de la dificultad que estás teniendo para resolverlo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes del ciclo declara un par de variables, un string que toma la respuesta y una bool que toma el si.

```
bool bandera = false;
string respuesta;
do{

//Lo que necesitas en tu ciclo
bandera = true;
Console.WriteLine("¿Desea algún dato nuevo? Si/No");
respuesta = Console.ReadLine();
if(respuesta.ToLower().Equals("si")) bandera = false;
}while(bandera);
```

El do while se ejecutara mientras responda si

Comment: Quizá sería mejor emplear `equals`,  además convertir con  `upper` o `lower`   las cadenas a comparar.

Comment: Como es muy nuevo en programación,  pensé que sería mejor no aplicarselo, pero ahí está

Comment: Está mal aplicado , no se aplica esto a un `boolean` ,  sería necesario solo uno `upper` o `lower` , no los dos.  por ejemplo `if(respuesta.ToLower().Equals("si"))`

Comment: Gracias ya quedo el programa!

Comment: Excelente! de nada

Answer (score 0):

Aquí puedes giarte con algo como esto.

```
  public void Add()
  {
         Console.WriteLine("Introduzca un texto");
         String texto;
         texto=Console.ReadLine();
         Console.WriteLine("El texto introducido es: " + texto);

        Console.WriteLine("Desea introducir otro texto");
         String Opcion;
         Opcion=Console.ReadLine();
         if(Opcion == "Si")
         { 
             Add();
         }
  }
```